# Offset the nth value in a range in excel

Tags: excel

very quick question, I'm trying to look up values in a range(the largest, 2nd largest, 3rd largest etc..) and then offset by one column. I thought something like the below would work;

```
=OFFSET(LARGE(C2:C116,1),0,-1)
```

But alas not... 
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=OFFSET(C2,MATCH(LARGE(C2:C116,1),C2:C116)-1,-1)
```

Use `MATCH` to find the numbner of rows to offset by (`-1` because `MATCH` 'indexes' from 1 but `OFFSET` 'indexes' from 0). Then set the reference field (first argument) in `OFFSET` to be the start of your range (i.e. `C2`)

Comment: Argh, not quite working, but many thanks for your reply. Basically, I've a list of outcomes in column A, such as 'Case Closed', 'Case Raised in Error' etc, and then in columns B-F, a count for each outcome for Mon-Fri. I want to lookup the max count, say for Monday, and then return the matching outcome.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure exactly why, but it just pulls through the final value in Column B. For example, if i have a range of (text) outcomes from A2:A11, and values in B2:B11, with the largest value in B3; using the formula  `=OFFSET(B2,MATCH(LARGE(B2:B11,1),B2:B11)-1,-1)` just pulls through the value of A11.

Comment: Got it working in the end with this `=INDEX(A2:A11,MATCH(LARGE(B2:B11,1),B2:B11,0))`. Cheers for your help.

Comment: @ex-patriot sure, `INDEX` is better anyway because it's not volatile, it will be a lot faster. Please accept the answer if it'sworking

Comment: @ex-patriot using the formula `=OFFSET(B2,MATCH(LARGE(B2:B11,1),B2:B11)-1,-1)` just pulls through the value of `A11`, that's very strange, I don't see why.